# Payment Gateway Duplicate transaction detection?

Tags: java, transactions, payment-gateway

I'm meeting some problem understanding how my current Payment Gateway([ProcessPink](http://www.processpink.com/)) identify duplicate transactions. The "document man" says:

> If there are 2 transactions for the same credit card, with the same
>   amount happen within 20 minutes, then they would be considered
>   duplicate. An error would be returned.

Personally I think this is a too-simple technique, which prevent our customers issue 2 orders: for example, there are 2 things with the same price in our online store, how can I tell that people should wait 20 minutes before trying to buy the second one?

Here's my questions:

1) Is this a popular practice for payment gateway? Or is there any alternative?

2) How can I work around this problem? I have thought of a shopping cart, but it doesn't fit my context. In short, my application need to perform 2 or more separate transactions (from the same card and with the same amount) within 20 minutes.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Yes, but usually the time window is smaller and adjustable. Authorize.Net's is 3 minutes by default and you can change that with a parameter during the transaction.
2. Do an authorization only on the second purchase and then capture it after 20 minutes. It's a pain in the butt to set up and do but I can't see any other user-friendly way around this.

Comment: Hi John, but how I know that the user will do the second transactions? If before 20 minutes passed, the user do another transactions, and then do another one.... I don't know how long it would take then.

Comment: I think that I will implement like the way of Google Checkout (I guess): a queue for orders, and an order only get sent AFTER its "twin" brother was sent(for 20 minutes ). Then the error in transaction (if exists) would be reported through emails

Comment: In the end we simulate the "package" option, which allow buyers to add multiple same price "plan" into the package. It isn't so good with our interface at the time, but we do it anyway.

Answer (score -1):

Your system could generate a unique key on each transaction. Then implement an auto-validation mechanism: if the system detects a duplicate key then it should deny it.

Comment: Could add more details?

Comment: thanks for your answer. For my specific case at the time, I already use different Order ID. The fact here is that the payment gateway (not in our control) just drop any requests with same (Credit Card number, amount) within 20 minutes

Comment: While this might be a valuable hint to solve the problem, an
answer really needs a bit more detail than this.  Please
[edit] to provide example code to show what you mean.
Alternatively, consider writing this as a comment instead.